# Drupal gets into loop when calling input text change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-7

I'm working with Drupal 7, the problem is that I have an input type text for the quantity of the products with 2 arrows in span by default (widget quantity for the add cart button).

When using the js_injector module for getting the 'change()' event of the input, something weird happens and a loop started changing the value of the input for more or less depending of the clicked arrow.

```
    jQuery(function($) {
        $(document).ready(function(){
              $('#edit-quantity').bind('change keydown keyup click input submit mouseenter', function (e) {alert('Type: ' + e.type); });

        });
      });
```

->This works correctly but doesn't get the arrow-span clicked options:

```
     $('#edit-quantity').bind('keydown keyup click input submit mouseenter',...
```

->These options create a loop:

```
     $('#edit-quantity').bind('change ...',
```

OR

```
     $('#edit-quantity').change(function (e) {alert('Type: ' + e.type); });
```

My point is , Why this .change() event creates such a loop? or better how can I stop it to use the event?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it helps someone, at the end I just did search for all the possibilities of change. Not only in the input also at the 'buttons' represented with span. I did some little trick and ended up like this:

```
    jQuery(function($) {
    function value()
    {
       if($(this).index()!=0) //Just execute once
       {
               var price=parseFloat(document.getElementsByClassName('field-item')[0].innerHTML.replace(' €','')).toFixed(2);
               var quantity = parseFloat($("#edit-quantity").val());
               price *= quantity;
               var glbvar = price.toFixed(2).replace('.',',')+' €';

       //Set Price
               document.getElementsByClassName('field-name-commerce-price')[0].getElementsByClassName('field-item')[0].innerHTML = glbvar ;
       }
    }

      $(document).ready(function(){
       //When refreshing the value get lost:
            if( parseFloat($("#edit-quantity").val()) != 1)  value();


    /*For input*/ $("#edit-quantity").bind("propertychange keyup paste input",value);
    /*For span*/  $('span').bind('click',value);

       });
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "input" instead of change

```
$('#textbox').on('input', function() {
    // do your stuff
});
```

Better not to use change on text field. Change is more preferred for radio button, select field, check-box etc...

Comment: Thank you @JSunny but I already put the 'input' between the options as you can see in the second line of code. It's not a complete solution as it doesn't have into consideration the 'buttons' that increase or decrease the value or even the keyword arrows.